# My laptop won’t boot . Error : hci0 failed to send intel_write_ddc (-22)

Tags: boot

When I start my laptop, it fails to boot because of this error:

```
Bluetooth: hci0 failed to send intel_write_ddc (-22)
```

Comment: After this error, the laptop should continue booting, not stop.

Comment: It should take time ? Because mine appears freezed

Answer (score 6):

I also had this, and wasted hours until I realized it wasn't a boot problem at all.

What happened what that the GUI was just gone, and for some reason that intel_write_ddc error ended up sitting there on the screen, insteead of any indication of what was really happening. The bluetooth error was probably there all along.

But switching to tty1 (`ctrl`+`alt`+`F1`) revealed that boot was successful and everything was there, so I've just ran `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and got my GUI back.

Comment: This helped me. I touched some theme packages before, maybe some more, and on a reboot, I couldn't enter the desktop GUI anymore. After switching to the tty1 and installing the ubuntu-desktop package, my GUI got back.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the end problem, not what caused it. I booted into an earlier kernel and looked at `rfkill`.

```
$ rfkill list
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

This command fixed it for me:

```
$ rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

I'm not sure what caused it but it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem earlier today. The action that led to the issue for me is that I rolled back my graphics card driver using the additional drivers tab in "Software & Updates". To fix this I just rolled back my roll-back.

Once the boot appears to start use (`ctrl`+`alt`+`F2`) to move to tty2. I then logged in with my usual details. Typing `ubuntu-drivers devices` I saw a list of the available drivers for my graphics card and then I installed the relevant one using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-455`.

Answer (score 0):

I was wasting my time for a couple hour for the solution and end up with reinstalling another version of my vga driver (from nvidia-driver-455 to 450) through recovery kernel boot. I'm using 5.6.1034 oem ubuntu kernel and installed the driver using synaptic package manager. Dont forget to choose your related driver on Additional Drivers window. Oyaa, actually this problem came up after I installed newest nvidia driver which is in 455 version.

Answer (score 0):

When you see the **Bluetooth: hci0: Reading...**, do `CTRL+ALT+F2` to reach tty2 and then press `CTRL+ALT+F1` to make it to login screen. Its not a solution but will unblock you from using your linux. I  myself have wasted countless hours with no solution