# Ubutuntu 22.04 won't boot - can't interrupt bluetooth errors

Tags: boot, 22.04, login, bluetooth

I cannot boot my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS laptop. The boot starts, but then it gets stuck on bluetooth errors. The same error repeats endlessly:

```
[    XXXXX] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-38)
```

(the XXXXX just increases with each message.

I tried to interrupt it using Ctrl-Alt-F2 (or F3) as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290395/my-laptop-won-t-boot-error-hci0-failed-to-send-intel-write-ddc-22) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/owbdc3/boot_error_bluetooth_failed_to_send_firmware_data/). A login prompt appears, but I cannot login as more bluetooth errors appear.

How can I interrupt the errors so I can log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shift or ESC at boot to get the Grub Menu, press e to edit, scroll down to you find "quiet splash", then make it "modprobe.blacklist=btusb quiet splash" then press F10 to boot using that parameter